# Designation of the 'ROWS' keyword in the PIVOT after Merge Statement

Tags: merge, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I have this code immediately following a merege statement. I'm confused with the '1 rows' keyword in the code below.

Can someone explain me what do I need it for?

This code is before the merge statement.

```
CREATE TABLE #UpdatedRecords 
        (
            -- Create variable needed to count different merge operations
            mergeAction NVARCHAR(10)
        );
```

/*====
THE MERGE STATEMENT LOGIC IS HERE..
====*/

```
OUTPUT  $action
        INTO #UpdatedRecords
        ;

        SET @RC = @@ROWCOUNT;

        SELECT   @insertMAddressTypeCount=[INSERT]
        ,        @updateMAddressTypeCount=[UPDATE]
        FROM    (
                SELECT  mergeAction,1 rows
                FROM    #UpdatedRecords
                ) p
        PIVOT
        (
            COUNT(rows)
        FOR    mergeAction IN 
        (    [INSERT], [UPDATE], [DELETE])
        ) AS pvt
        ;
```

Comment: It's a column alias for the literal value 1. You could just as well remove the column entirely and use `count(*)` instead. Basically it does nothing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just added the #UpdatedRecords table definition for your reference.

Comment: Basically the '1' in the '1 rows'  section is the first column from the left in the  #UpdatedRecords table. Correct?

Comment: No, it's the second column in a logical ("temporary") table called `p`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `1 rows` portion of the query adds a column with constant value `1` to the derived table ("subquery") named `p`. That value is used for counting via `count(rows)` although ultimately it's unnecessary since `count(*)` gives the same result.

Here's an equivalent query without the `pivot` that you might find useful or enlightening:

```
select
    @inserts = count(case when mergeAction = 'INSERT' then 1 end),
    @updates = count(case when mergeAction = 'UPDATE' then 1 end)
from #UpdatedRecords;
```

**EDIT:** I forgot that `pivot` doesn't support the `count(*)` operation and `count(mergeAction)` doesn't work either. So that's the reason for the dummy column in OP's query.

Comment: Thanks a  lot. Did you deliberately skipped the [DELETE] column that was present in my code above? I assume you skipped it in your answer as I's not needing it since my Merge does not do any "delete" operations.

Comment: I only skipped it because your query did too ;) There wasn't a variable being set for that value.